# Creating unnecessary string objects

Tags: java, string

This is a bit of Java String 101.  I came across this recently in some existing code.  My initial reaction is that this is redundant

```
car.setDetails(new String(someStringBufferObj.toString));
```

In my opinion *even this would be redundant*...

```
car.setDetails(new String(someOtherStringObj));
```

because String is immutable so there is never a risk that the car details would be changed accidentally (by changing `someOtherStringObj`) in a later line of code

Are am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Both of those snippet is simply creating unnecesary strings, provided your `someOtherString` is a `String` only.

Comment: Not necessarily. I agree re. example 1 but not re. example 2. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet above looks unnecessary. However the second may be necessary. Consider the following.

The constructor `String(String)` is useful since it'll take a *copy* of the underlying character array of the original string.

Why is this useful ? You have to understand that a string object has a character array underlying it, and getting a `substring()` of an existing string actually uses that original character array. This is a [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Consider the following

```
String s = longstring.substring(2,4);
```

The string `s` points to the character array underlying `longstring` (somewhat unintuitively). If you want to bin `longstring` (using garbage collection) the underlying character array *won't* be binned since `s` still references it, and you end up consuming a potentially huge amount of memory for a 2 character string.

The `String(String)` constructor resolves this by creating a new character array from that referenced by the string being used to construct from. When the original string is removed via garbage collection its character array won't be referenced by the `substring()` result and hence that will be removed too.

Note that this behaviour has changed very recently in Java (release 7u4, I think) and strings don't support the above mode of operation anymore.

Comment: And whenever or not it's usefull, I don't think it's redundant. Doesn't that word cover an entirely other thing?

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right Rob, there's no need to new up a String in this instance.  Just providing a call to someStringBufferObj.toString() should be sufficient!

Comment: `someStringBufferObj` != `someOtherStringObj`

Comment: @PremGenError. He is probably referring to the first snippet.